# How can I update the field value of all objects in a queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to update a field 'volume' to volume += change_by.
I want to increase the existing value of that field for all the objects in the queryset by 'change_by' variable, whatever the 'change_by' variable contains.

```
queryset = QueueStatusModel.objects.all()
queryset.update(volume+=iph_change)
```

This didn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the documentation link in the comments @iklinac
From that documentation I could find this:

```
queryset.update(volume=F('volume') + iph_change)
```

Answer (score 1):

use a for loop for each object of queryset.

```
queryset = QueueStatusModel.objects.all() 

for q in queryset:
    q.volume += iph_change
    q.save()
```

note: this will increase volume of any object of QueueStatusModel for each request that comes through this view function

Comment: depending on the size of the operation, this could get real expensive and brittle... at very least would be good to wrap the update in a transaction https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic